# libgdi32.a library while using CImg

Tags: c++, dev-c++, cimg

I'm trying to run this short code that I found in another SO post. However, I keep on getting this error:

C:\Users\ndeangelis\AppData\Local\Temp\ccK7X4dd.o   test.cpp:(.text$_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay5paintEv[_ZN12cimg_library11CImgDisplay5paintEv]+0xb7): undefined reference to `__imp_SetDIBitsToDevice'

After doing some research I found that I'm supposed to include the libgdi32.a library and I have done so under Project Options->Parameters->Add library or object. However the error persists. Here is the code:

```
#include "C:\Users\ndeangelis\Desktop\CImg-1.7.4\CImg.h"

using namespace cimg_library;

int main() {

CImg<unsigned char> image("dog.bmp");
image = image.resize(64, 64, -100, -100, 3);
CImgDisplay main_disp(image,"Image resized");
   while (!main_disp.is_closed() ) 
     main_disp.wait();

    return 0;

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Yes it is similar to that one however as I was saying I tried the solution suggested and it hasn't worked :/

Comment: I deleted the other post

Comment: I use dev-c++ 5.11

Answer (score 0):

I now realized my mistake!
When creating a new folder I selected the wrong type: should be Empty Project!